# CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE with SELECT FROM not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to get the following to work within php:

```
<?php

$qry="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coursesearch` AS (

     SELECT  `TREKKER_ID`, `TREKKER_COMPANY`, `TREKKER_FULLDISPLAYNAME`, `TREKKER_POSTCODE`, 
             `TREKKER_ACTIVE`, `TREKKER_SUBSCRIBOPN`, `tbl_trials`.*, 
             `EROUTE_RIDERID`, `EROUTE_FKID`, `EROUTE_EXPIRYDATE` 

      FROM `tbl_trekks`, 
           `tbl_trials`, 
           `tbl_scores`

      WHERE `TREKKER_POSTCODE`" . $pcode .
      " AND `tbl_trials`.`TRIALID` = `tbl_trekks`.`TREKKER_ID`";

      if( $checkscores===true ) 
      {
          $qry.=" OR (`tbl_scores`.`EROUTE_RIDERID` = `tbl_trekks`.`TREKKER_ID` 
                  AND `tbl_scores`.`EROUTE_FKID` <> 0)";
      }


$qry.= "); SELECT * FROM `coursesearch`;";

if(   !is_array($arr = $dbOb->DB_runQuery("slt", $qry ))   ) { return 0; }
else {
    print_r( $arr );
}   

?>
```

Ive tested it directly in the phpMyAdmin console and this works (Obviously without the php specific code and tags) the result set is displayed in the temp table 'coursesearch'. However running the code in php gives this standard error message :

> Error: DB Class: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM coursesearch' at line 14.

I understand from researching in google and the mysql site that temporary tables dissappear once the script finishes but surely i'm outputting the resultset before the script finishes. Ive tried using aliases and prefixing all fields with their respective tables names, also tried without backticks in PHP - but the problem persists on the same line,

> near 'SELECT * FROM coursesearch' at line 14

Have i misunderstood what temporary tables can achieve here??

Answer (score 1):

Either use PHP `multi_query()` in `mysqli` or separate these into two separate queries (run separately)

If that means adding such functionality to your `$dbOb->` to run a DB_runMultiQuery (that you have to write) instead of calling `$dbOb->DB_runQuery`, then that is what you have to do.

PHP Manual page on [Multi Query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

> Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a
>   semicolon.

Comment: Hi, I've implemented the Multi_Query method (Procedural style) as in example 2 from the link you supplied. But my first query is a 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE' and does not produce a result-set - The second query is the SELECT FROM query which im trying to view with print_r just to see if my query has produced the result i want. After this i will be quering the new table. Im not understanding how this works with multi-query - my home grown solution was almost identical - but i need to **Create Temp** - **Confirm Creation** then - **SELECT** - im struggling with the mysqli syntax to achieve this

Comment: A simple question for you: does using `multi_query()` get you past the syntax error? Yes or No?

Comment: Yes the error has now gone - new message in Chrome Inspector is: Strict Standards: mysqli_next_result() [function.mysqli-next-result.chm]: There is no next result set.

Comment: great, we have established that this Question is answered. Mark accordingly. I am available in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/random-musings-drew for any off topic questions, whenever